# graphic, add correspondence point and add 0 in central of axes

Tags: pgfplots

i have this code for make this function
[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\def\FunctionF(#1){(#1)^3- 3*(#1)}%

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
        axis y line=center,
        axis x line=middle, 
        axis on top=true,
        xmin=-5.5,
        xmax=5.5,
        ymin=-45,
        ymax=45,
        height=12.0cm,
        width=12.0cm,
        grid,
        xtick={-5,...,5},
        ytick={-40,-32,...,40},
    ]
    \addplot [domain=-5:5, samples=50, mark=none, ultra thick, blue] {\FunctionF(x)};
    \node [left, blue] at (axis cs: 3.6,42) {$x^3-3x$};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

but i need add this in like you see in red color

how to add a correspondence point,  if possible in different colors better

and, add the zero in the center of the intersection of the axes, because in horizontal skip -1 to 1 and vertical skip -8 to 8.

thanks

[image]

Comment: Try this: `\addplot[thick,red,dashed] coordinates {(3,0) (3,{\FunctionF(3)}) (0,{\FunctionF(3)})};`

Comment: works, as could that thicker dotted line. and you know how to add the central 0. thank you

Comment: using "extra x tick style" what command can i use for move 0 a little to right for avoid it apper over axis. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this?

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
declare function = {f(\t)=(\t)^3- 3*(\t);},
        height=12.0cm,
        width=12.0cm,
        axis lines=center,
        grid,
        xmin=-5.5,
        xmax=5.5,
        ymin=-45,
        ymax=45,
        ticklabel style = {font=\footnotesize,  inner sep=1pt,
                           fill=white},
        xtick={-5,...,2,4,5},
        ytick={-40,-32,...,40},
        extra x ticks = {0,3},
        extra y ticks = {18},
        extra x tick style = {grid=none, color=red},
        extra y tick style = {color=red}
    ]
\addplot +[domain=-5:5, samples=51, mark=none, ultra thick] {f(x)} 
    node [pos=0.7, left=2mm] {$x^3-3x$};
\draw[dashed, semithick, red]  (3,0) |- (0,18) node[pos=0.5, circle, inner sep=2pt, fill=red] {};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```